# How to use 'using' keyword properly in C++

Tags: c++, using

I need to know about the scopes that I can use 'using' keyword in C++.

Let's suppose we have two CPP files in the same code base that have used the 'using' keyword with the same type name.

A.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
namespace space_A
{
    typedef struct myStruct
    {
        int a;
        myStruct(): a(1) {}
    } MyStruct;
}

using my_type = space_A::MyStruct;

void func_A()
{
    my_type *t_a = new my_type();
    std::cout<<t_a->a;
}
```

B.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
namespace space_B
{
    typedef struct myStruct
    {
        char *b;
        myStruct(): b((char*)"xyz") {}
    } MyStruct;
}

using my_type = space_B::MyStruct;

void func_B()
{
    my_type *t_b = new my_type();
    std::cout<<t_b->b;
}
```

Could there be conflicts on those "using my_type = ...." lines (actually for the usage points-(func_a, func_b)) on that two files?
Simply, is that 'my_type' local to the respective file scope?

Comment: `typedef struct myStruct` -- In C++, `typedef struct` is not necessary.  Just `struct myStruct` is all that's needed.

Comment: ok, but I'm focusing here on 'using my_type=..'.
eg: Could 'my_type' in A.cpp be visible inside B.cpp's func_B ?

Comment: No, only if the `using` is in the header files. On different `cpp` files you are safe. if you are not sure at questions like that, you can always just write it in your code and check if you are getting any errors.

Comment: @רועיאבידן This is good practice in general, but the compiler may not be able to diagnose things like ODR violations, which is a possibility in cases like this.

Comment: We can use 'static' keyword to declare a function local to the file (in C). I need such behavior for this "using my_type =...." (if I use my_type in file A.cpp, then my_type must be the A.cpp's one). is that behavior available in those files now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various C++ Standards are quite verbose (but nonetheless vague) when it comes to providing *formal* definitions of the *scope* of variable names and related identifiers (such as the *alias-declaration* that the `using` keyword introduces). For example, [this Draft (C++17) Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) says the following:

> **6.3.1 Declarative regions and scopes**
>  1 Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a declarative
> region, which is the largest part of the program in which that name is
> valid, that is, in which that name may be used as an unqualified name
> to refer to the same entity. In general, each particular name is valid
> only within some possibly discontiguous portion of program text called
> its scope. To determine the scope of a declaration, it is sometimes
> convenient to refer to the potential scope of a declaration. The scope
> of a declaration is the same as its potential scope unless the
> potential scope contains another declaration of the same name. In that
> case, the potential scope of the declaration in the inner (contained)
> declarative region is excluded from the scope of the declaration in
> the outer (containing) declarative region.

This (to me, at least) is not especially informative, except for this sentence: *To determine the scope of a declaration, it is sometimes convenient
to refer to the potential scope of a declaration.* What can be inferred from this is that, if you *cannot* refer to the `my_type` definition given in "A.cpp" from *within* "B.cpp," then you are allowed to provide another (potentially different) such definition in that file.

Another possibly useful extract from that standard occurs a few pages later, under the **6.3.6 Namespace scope** section:

> *the potential scope of l is from its point of declaration to the end
> of the translation unit*

This statement also holds true for other declarations: the scope of each of your `my_type` aliases is from the point of each declaration to the end of the translation unit (the source file in which that declaration occurs).

However, as pointed out in the comments to your question, although such 'duplication' of an alias is within the rules of the C++ language, the practice *could* lead to problems later on (at the link stage), especially when using such techniques as link-time code generation, cross-module run-time linkage (DLLs) and debuggers.

Comment: We can use 'static' keyword to declare a function local to the file (in C). I need such behavior for this "using my_type =...." (if I use my_type in file A.cpp, then my_type must be the A.cpp's one). is that behavior available in those files now?

Comment: @yasaramalshan Yes. According to the C++ Standard(s), each of your two source files will *only* be able to use the `my_type` alias defined in *that* file. Each source file is an **independent** translation unit, and cannot be aware of things defined or declared outside those files (other than in included headers, obviously).